# How to delay evaluation of python expression passed inside __init__

Tags: python

I have a scenario where I want to use logical operators between classes that are passed to **init** of another class. But, I want to postpone the evaluation of the operators to calling the object Basically inside `__call__`. There, I want to pass some more arguments that are needed for the logical operators.

Basically, I want to achieve this interface:

```
IsAllowed(classes=[Auth1('some_value') | Auth2('some_other_value')]
```

But, I want to postpone the evaluation of `classes=[Auth1('some_value') | Auth2('some_other_value')` to the time where `__call__` is called on `IsAllowed` and pass some extra args that are used in the logical operation.

And this is how `Auth` classes could look like under the hood:

```
class Auth:

    def __or__(self, other):
        return self.has_perm(run_time_arg) or other.has_perm(run_time_arg)
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Could you say a little more about why you want to "postpone the evaluation" and what exactly you mean by that? `__call__` is called exactly when your `IsAllowed` line is evaluated, isn't it?

Comment: where does `run_time_arg` come from?

Comment: The reason I want to postpone is that the evaluation of `has_perm` inside auth classes depends on some runtime value (for instance some request header value). 

By Postpone I mean that I want the __or__ logic to be evaluated when I call `__call__` with some param on the runtime and not as soon as the interpreter runs the module.

Comment: This Class will be used inside FastAPI framework as a Depenency. The web framework will call the instances of `IsAllowed` with specific runtime params (user requests etc.)

Comment: Which class has a `__call__`? Is it the class of `IsAllowed`?

Comment: @AndrewJaffe. The frame work uses __call__ on `IsAllowed`.

Comment: Ah, so you don't want the argument of `IsAllowed` to be evaluated at definition. Perhaps just define a new function which takes your `'some_value'` and `'some_other_value'` and bundles them up into `Auth` only when run?

Comment: You understood me correctly Andrew. Could you share some code regarding your suggestion please?

Comment: So the thing that isn't defined yet is `some_value`? Easy enough.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to allow deferred execution (with `some_value` provided at that later time), rearrange the API to let your caller pass a lambda:

```
IsAllowed(classesFn = lambda value: [Auth1(value) | Auth2(value)])
```

...and then have the callee invoke that function to get the value it returns.

---

This might look something like:

```
class IsAllowed(object):
    def __init__(self, classesFn=None):
        self.classesFn = classesFn
    def __call__(self, value):
        classes = self.classesFn(value)
        # do logic using 'classes' here
```

Comment: Looks promising. There are more challenges to what I want though, I just revised the question. Could you have another expert look?

Comment: @AmirAfianian, see updates. Mind, next time, please try to be sure your question is complete enough to be answered as initially asked -- questions that change answers are not considered quite kosher here; while it was easy enough to accommodate this time, often we ask that a new question be asked instead of making an edit that invalidates answers that were correct before the question changed.

Comment: Thanx. You're right. Do you think it's possible to inject this lambda into the init using metaclasses (or `__init__subclass` hook) to keep the interface more simple?

Comment: @AmirAfianian, I'd need a better understanding of what you're trying to accomplish, but generally, the decision about what parameters to pass happens before the invocation actually starts, so the code being invoked doesn't have the chance to rework how those parameters are constructed.

Comment: @AmirAfianian, ...now, what you _could_ do is change your `Auth` objects to allow a usage mode where they can be compounded even with `value` not applied yet; but that's far too involved a bit of rework to fit into the question here.

Answer (score 1):

How about just deferring until call time by not actually executing the `__or__` until then:

```py
def IsAllowedAuth12(value1, value2):

    return IsAllowed(classes=[Auth1(value1) | Auth2(value2)])
```

Comment: Hmm, could work. But the bitwise logic will be hidden under the IsAllowed class while I want it to be exposed in its init.